# Parabola - how to write equation of parabola when co-ordinates are given..

Tags: conic-sections

What will be the equation of parabola touching the $x$-axis at $(3,0)$ and and the $y$-axis at $(0,4)$.

Comment: Do you have any other points or other information?  There are a lot of parabolas that can match those criteria...

Comment: Does "touching" mean a tangential intersection ("osculation")?

Comment: Based on the OP’s comment to one of the answers, it looks like the parabola is meant to be tangent to the coordinate axes at those points.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you would like to know the equation of the parabola of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ whose only intersections with the coordinate axes are $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$.

In this case note that the parabola is tangent to the $x$-axis at $(3,0)$ (why?). Therefore $y=a(x-3)^2$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If $y(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then I assume, that you have to determine $a,b$ and $c$ under the conditions

$y(0)=4$, $y(3)=0$ and $y'(3)=0$.

I am right ?

Comment: Parabola only touches the x axis and y-axis ...it doesn't intersects the axes....

Comment: It would appear that the parabola must be tangent to the coordinate axes, so it can’t be expressed in the form you’re suggesting.